# SQL query does not work, store_result crashes the execution

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
   //include 'globals.php';

   $mysqli = new mysqli(correct...);

   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error();
   }

   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

   if($query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?"))
   {
   $query->bind_param("s", $username);
   $query->execute();
   //$query->store_result();

      $result = $query->num_rows;
      echo sprintf("Row: %d", $result);
      if($result != 0)
      {
         $row = $query->fetch_array();
         if(password_verify($password, $row["password"]))
         {
            echo 'Success';
         }
         else
         {
            echo 'Failed';
         }
      }
      else 
      {
         echo 'Empty';
      }

   }
   $mysqli->close();
?>
```

If I don't do store_result() the row will always return 0 (perhaps the query is going wrong?)
However if I do the query on the PHPMYADMIN it works well.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check if your $_POST is set with values. Further, never use this code in production.

Comment: You need to call `store_result` on `$mysqli`, not `$query`, as it's part of [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php), not [`mysqli_stmt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) **Edit** Ugh, I'm wrong, [it is](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)

Comment: $_POST is set with values @Grumpy

Comment: I will check @aynber thank you for the response let me check.

Comment: Can store result but still returns 0 on num_rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

**Instead**

```
   $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '?'");
```

**Do**

```
$query = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$query->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '?'");
```

Thanks everyone who contributed. Hope this helps someone else.